# Join several selects

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have tables like this fake ones:

```
data:
    id  type    month   value
    1   1       1       10
    2   1       2       20
    3   1       3       30
    4   2       1       40
    5   2       2       50
    6   2       3       60
    7   3       1       70
    8   3       2       80
    9   3       3       90
    10  4       1       100
    11  4       2       110
    12  4       3       120

type:
    id  name
    1   A
    2   B
    3   C
    4   D

What I want:
    month   valueA  valueB  valueC  valueD
    1       10      40      70      100
    2       20      50      80      110
    3       30      60      90      120
```

How can I make this query?
I'm using Oracle 10g.

Comment: Why don't you enter the question *here* instead of making a screenshot of your text editor? Screenshots of text are next to useless.

Comment: Sorry, but when I tried to post using text it lost its spaces, and It looks like [code][/code] doesn't work here. Tell me how to do it and I'll edit.

Comment: @LZZ: when editing your question there is a little question mark in the upper right corner which gives you all the formatting help you need.

Comment: @LZZ: Plus, formatting help is literally *slapped in your face*. It takes a good deal of mental shielding to ignore it. Next time: Read some more. Assume that *you* might also be able to post formatted text when others on the site are. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want a relatively straightforward pivot of the data.  If you were using 11g, you could use the more elegant PIVOT function.  But in 10g, you could still do something like this

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with data as (
  2    select 1 id, 1 type, 1 month, 10 value from dual union all
  3    select 2,1,2,20 from dual union all
  4    select 3,1,3,30 from dual union all
  5    select 4,2,1,40 from dual union all
  6    select 5,2,2,50 from dual union all
  7    select 6,2,3,60 from dual union all
  8    select 7,3,1,70 from dual union all
  9    select 8,3,2,80 from dual union all
 10    select 9,3,3,90 from dual union all
 11    select 10,4,1,100 from dual union all
 12    select 11,4,2,110 from dual union all
 13    select 12,4,3,120 from dual
 14  ),
 15  type as (
 16    select 1 id, 'A' name from dual union all
 17    select 2,'B' from dual union all
 18    select 3,'C' from dual union all
 19    select 4,'D' from dual)
 20  select d.month,
 21         max(case when t.name = 'A' then d.value else null end) valueA,
 22         max(case when t.name = 'B' then d.value else null end) valueB,
 23         max(case when t.name = 'C' then d.value else null end) valueC,
 24         max(case when t.name = 'D' then d.value else null end) valueD
 25    from data d,
 26         type t
 27   where d.type = t.id
 28*  group by d.month
SQL> /

     MONTH     VALUEA     VALUEB     VALUEC     VALUED
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1         10         40         70        100
         2         20         50         80        110
         3         30         60         90        120
```

Comment: +1 for effort, I'm tired just looking at that

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even expected such a complete answer, I would be happy with a "This is called Pivot".Thank you very much and sorry for the work of typing all those numbers.

Comment: That was a lot of work. It's also called crosstab in other environments.

Answer (score 1):

Just like this ...

```
SELECT month
      ,SUM(valueA) AS valueA
      ,SUM(valueB) AS valueB
      ,SUM(valueC) AS valueC
      ,SUM(valueD) AS valueD
FROM (
SELECT month , DECODE(type,1,value,0) valueA
             , DECODE(type,2,value,0) valueB
             , DECODE(type,3,value,0) valueC
             , DECODE(type,4,value,0) valueD
FROM DATA)
GROUP BY month
order by month
```